# IlllegalStateException when I add @Bean to main class

Tags: java, spring-boot, illegalstateexception

When I add this to my application class

```
@Bean
HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
    return new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();
}
```

My application won't start and gives this error:

> 2021-11-16 08:11:08.950 ERROR 70458 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.paulcarron.learningspringboot.learningspringboot.LearningSpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.paulcarron.learningspringboot.learningspringboot.LearningSpringBootApplication
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
> at com.paulcarron.learningspringboot.learningspringboot.LearningSpringBootApplication.main(LearningSpringBootApplication.java:12) ~[main/:na]
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.paulcarron.learningspringboot.learningspringboot.LearningSpringBootApplication
> at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:162) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.paulcarron.learningspringboot.learningspringboot.LearningSpringBootApplication
>
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:326) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> ... 13 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.paulcarron.learningspringboot.learningspringboot.LearningSpringBootApplication] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@22d8cfe0]
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.paulcarron.learningspringboot.learningspringboot.LearningSpringBootApplication] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@22d8cfe0]
>
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:455) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:151) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> ... 18 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
>
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3334) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2446) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> ... 20 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
>
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
> ... 51 common frames omitted
>
> Execution failed for task ':LearningSpringBootApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command '/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> What does it mean and how do I resolve it?

Comment: It needs to be `public` or `protected`. And please add the full stacktrace instead of just a snippet. However you shouldn't even need this filter as this is registered already by Spring Boot (or actually the `OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter` from Spring Boot. ALthough in newer versions this might be disabled, instead add `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` to your `application.properties` to have it switched on.

Comment: Sorry, full stacktrace added. So `OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter` gets registered automatically?

Comment: yes, but it might require a property (see comment) if you have a newer version (it was disabled as the majority uses Spring Boot for REST based microservices, this filter is only needed for HTML forms that are being submitted (as your browser only supports GET/POST).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` to `application.properties` to have it switched on.